# Async function with Firestore does not load my data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

on my page on `nOnInit` I use a async function to load some data from firebase (normally the async function wait to get all the data from firebase), so this work correctly and I got my data inside my object `getDocu`

```js
async ngOnInit() {
    this.getDocu = await this.Help.getLastTime('JOURNALIER', 'Le Mat', 'lastTime', 'lastTime');
    this.loadItems();
}
```

Then, inside this page, the user fill in some questions and I am saving the results inside the same document (update) in firebase and when I come back on the page I run `ionViewWillEnter` to reload the updated data and display it on my page.

```js
async ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.getDocu = await this.Help.getLastTime('JOURNALIER', 'Le Mat', 'lastTime', 'lastTime');
    this.loadItems();
}
```

Here is my `getLastTime` function :

```js
async getLastTime(collectionName: string, user: string, collec: string, docu: string) {
    const docRef = this.afs.firestore.collection(collectionName).doc(user).collection(collec).doc(docu);
    const doc = await docRef.get();
    if (doc.exists) {
            this.getDocu = doc.data();
        } else {
            this.getDocu = 'Never done';
        }
    return this.getDocu;
  }
```

But when I console log the result of `ionViewWillEnter`, I do not load the updated data, or if I reload the page manually, this time this is `ngOnInit` that runs and got the updated value...

Very strange to me, since it looks like I use the same method to get the value... with different results..

Comment: When you enter, the ngOnInit + ionViewWillEnter will execute. DRY by removing the functionality out of ngOnInit

Comment: So I put nothing inside ngOnInit ? I tried it gives the same result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.valueChanges()` or `.snapShotChanges()` instead of `.get()`. You can subscribe to the former methods, which makes it obsolete to call a query like `ionViewWillEnter()`. After the values have been updated, you will automatically receive the values again.

Rewrite `getLastTime()` (assuming it's in the Service `firebaseService`) to return an Observable:

```
getLastTime(collectionName: string, user: string, collec: string, docu: string) {
    return this.afs.collection(collectionName).doc(user).collection(collec).doc(docu).valueChanges();
  }
```

In your component, subscribe to `getLastTime()`:

```
this.firebaseService.getLastTime(....).subscribe(res => {
 if (!res) 
   console.log("never done");
});
```

Comment: Thank you but `.valueChanges()` or `.snapShotChanges()`do not exists..

Comment: Are you using Angularfire? Can you share your service (especially this.afs)?

Comment: Yes. `private afs: AngularFirestore`

Comment: I edited the getLastTime function, can you confirm .valueChanges () is still not available?

Comment: now .valueChanges is correct but I cannot not subscribe to getLastTime as you have done...

Comment: Remove async from getLastTime()